# Is there any alternative to the websockets for using in shared hosting

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, real-time

Is there any alternative for the websockets to use in shared hosting? I know about node.js, socket.io, Express.js but Can't use them in shared hosting. So, if there is any alternative used for making a realtime website then tell me.

Comment: Your best bet would be to get a VPS instead, they go for as low as $5/mo

Comment: Get a VPS. Shared hosting sites usually have certain limitations due to their internal server organization.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529613/why-node-js-cant-run-on-shared-hosting

Comment: @Ineentho Did you mean a web server hosting from office or home? if it is then it is very difficult for me that I'm in Pakistan and there is load shedding of electricity. So, Please tell me is there any other thing to use in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your shared hosting provides PHP support, you can use one of the WebSockets libraries in PHP:

- [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/)
- [phpwebsocket](https://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/)
- [PHP-WebSockets](https://github.com/ghedipunk/PHP-WebSockets)

For installing Ratchet, read my answer on [how to install Composer on a shared hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26277355/912946).

Alternatively, you can install Node.js on a shared hosting using my project [Node.php](https://github.com/niutech/node.php).

Comment: does it mean that rachet can run in a shared hosting account

Comment: The options that you have suggested is based on a stand alone server

Comment: if you have `ssh` access you can use [websocketd](http://websocketd.com/) easy to use, quick to implement and free

Answer (score 7):

I think good alternative is "Server-Sent Events", it is one way but i think its in the most cases better that Websockets because its easier to setup as no special server or libraries needed and there is no extra protocol to follow, just `echo` from `php` and `onmessage` in `javascript`.

quick example (from https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp):

**Javascript**:

```
var source = new EventSource("demo_sse.php");
source.onmessage = function(event) {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += event.data + "<br>";
};
```

**PHP**:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');

$time = date('r');
echo "data: The server time is: {$time}\n\n";
flush();
?>
```

Comment: IMO this is really the best answer. The suggestions made in the accepted answer doesn't look to fulfill the needs of the OP. SSE is really the way to go on this.

Comment: Server sent events don't really work well with apache though

Comment: On my shared hosting the server doesn't send any messages. In localhost it works. How can I debug it?

Answer (score 3):

You may consider using a hosted realtime network like [PubNub](http://pubnub.com) for realtime communication on shared hosting. Using a hosted realtime solution like PubNub means you won't need to worry about open ports or persistent processes.

There is a full hello world tutorial to help you get started on the PubNub blog here:
http://www.pubnub.com/blog/php-push-api-walkthrough/

A simple example follows.

[image]

> Let’s take a look at how developers can create channels between PHP
>   and JavaScript. The most common usage pattern for real time
>   applications will be explained first. A JavaScript Browser (like
>   Firefox) will subscribe and listen for messages with
>   PUBNUB.subscribe(). PHP will then push messages with
>   $pubnub.publish().
>
> ```
> PUBNUB.subscribe( { channel : 'my_test_channel' }, function(message) {
> if ('some_text' in message) {
>     alert(message.some_text);
> }} );
> ```
>
> The above JavaScript is fully cross browser compatible. The code will
>   listen for messages published on ‘my_test_channel’ channel. When a
>   message is received, the JavaScript will validate if ‘some_text‘
>   exists in the message object. If this attribute exists, then show an
>   alert box!
>
> Now use PHP to publish a message to invoke the JavaScript Alert box.
>
> ```
> ## Publish Messages To a JavaScript Browser 
> $pubnub = new Pubnub( 'publish_key', 'subscribe_key' ); $pubnub->publish(array(
>   'channel' => 'my_test_channel',
>   'message' => array( 'some_text' => 'hello!' ) ));
> ```
>
> This PHP code will send a message to a JavaScript Browser listening on
>   ‘my_test_channel‘ channel. When this PHP Code executes, a JavaScript
>   Browser will receive the PHP array and show an alert message of
>   ‘hello!’.

http://www.pubnub.com/blog/php-push-api-walkthrough/#sthash.jI8zntnL.dpuf