# How to setup and run a PHP WebSocket service on a cpanel-based shared hosting platform?

Tags: php, cpanel, lamp, ratchet, phpwebsocket

I have created a Chat application in Ratchet PHP. It runs fine on local machine using WAMP. I want it to setup on live server.

On my server I have:

- PHP Support
- SSH access
- Port 9000, which is opened for OutBound connections.
- Sub-domains

What I don't have:

- No port for InBound connections.
- No root access in SSH. Say I cannot see/edit `iptables`

I ran `php server.php` which gives success message about the server is started and listening at port 9000. But when a HTML page tries to connect it using ws://domain:9000 it runs into error-

> Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at
>   ws://domain.com:9000/

I googled a lot and it appears that what I need is a port for inbound connections.

But according to [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29916806/5131768)  the thing I need is PHP support for Ratchet to work on shared hostings. Can anyone explains what I really need and Is there any workaround If it's not availble in the list of things I have on my server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Basically, No

It is not likely for a shared hosting environment (i.e. Apache with VirtualHost config, PHP, MySQL, and a CPanel interface) to support your websocket application.

For websocket to work, you need to either:

1. have a port dedicated to websocket in-bound connections; or
2. have a HTTP/HTTPS server that knows when to upgrade a connection and proxy pass to your websocket application.

The first route requires the server to allow in-bound connection to a certain port number. This is a potential security issue for the hosting provider and, thus, is unlikely for your vendor to grant you that.

The second route requires Apache server have with both [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html) and [mod_proxy_wstunnel](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_wstunnel.html) installed and enabled. It also require you to use [ProxyPass](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#ProxyPass) config, which cannot be overridden by `.htaccess` configs at all.

So unless your hosting grants you the permission to touch the Apache main configuration (or would apply such change for you), you're pretty hopeless.

### Suggestion

To run your own websocket service, you should think about using Virtual Private Server services such as Amazon EC2, DigitalOcean VPS.

Comment: Hey! This answer is pretty old, but I did want to provide some guidance here. You can get this done if you can get your host to cooperate. Either just run a systemd unit and open the port, use a cron with the port open, or you can use Include files to enable ProxyPass directives for one VirtualHost https://docs.cpanel.net/ea4/apache/modify-apache-virtual-hosts-with-include-files/

Comment: @PixelPerfect: Thanks for chipping in your thoughts. I think this answer still holds up. Your suggestion It's technically possible but is practically improbable. Either opening up TCP port (route 1) or allowing customer to touch a common server's config (route 2) would potentially generate security risk for their server. So unless you're a really important customer or a really good friend, it's not very likely that they would simply grant you that.

Comment: The intent of the include files is to isolate changes to a particular user. Also, most cPanel that I've ever logged into are either not behind a firewall, or running CSF, which allows for quickly opening ports right from WHM. By default, a service should be fine to just grab a port, provided you're not on AWS, GCP, MSAzure, or another VHost that has a default firewall set.

Comment: Officially, not supported by the cPanel product, correct, but there are workarounds. They would require that the host cooperate, and, yeah, many won't, but if you're using a shared server from a smaller host, it's actually more likely than you'd think.