# How to host a Node.Js application in shared hosting

Tags: node.js, web-hosting

How to host a Node.Js application in a shared hosting

I want to host a node.js application in shared hosting. Does anyone have any reference or documentation to refer to?

Comment: The way i figured it by running npm build will generate js files which you can minify and then include then in your script tags. Example when building with vuejs or even angular2 cli

Comment: this worked - shame I can't post an answer... https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/installable-applications/manual-installations/installing-node-js-on-managed-hosting-accounts

Comment: @Dan-Cornilescu can the be re-opened. It is valuable. It would be better in superuser. Also found an answer that I would like to add.

Comment: On most shared hosts installing Node and NPM will fail (CentOS Not Supported); here is a solution (using Node v6.2.2) - https://medium.com/@yatko/install-node-js-on-shared-hosting-65fb08deffad

Answer (score 179):

You **can** run node.js server on a typical shared hosting with Linux, Apache and PHP (LAMP). I have successfully installed it, even with NPM, Express and Grunt working fine. Follow the steps:

1) Create a new PHP file on the server with the following code and run it:

```php
<?php
//Download and extract the latest node
exec('curl http://nodejs.org/dist/latest/node-v0.10.33-linux-x86.tar.gz | tar xz');
//Rename the folder for simplicity
exec('mv node-v0.10.33-linux-x86 node');
```

2) The same way install your node app, e.g. jt-js-sample, using npm:

```php
<?php
exec('node/bin/npm install jt-js-sample');
```

3) Run the node app from PHP:

```php
<?php
//Choose JS file to run
$file = 'node_modules/jt-js-sample/index.js';
//Spawn node server in the background and return its pid
$pid = exec('PORT=49999 node/bin/node ' . $file . ' >/dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!');
//Wait for node to start up
usleep(500000);
//Connect to node server using cURL
$curl = curl_init('http://127.0.0.1:49999/');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
//Get the full response
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
if($resp === false) {
    //If couldn't connect, try increasing usleep
    echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($curl);
} else {
    //Split response headers and body
    list($head, $body) = explode("\r\n\r\n", $resp, 2);
    $headarr = explode("\n", $head);
    //Print headers
    foreach($headarr as $headval) {
        header($headval);
    }
    //Print body
    echo $body;
}
//Close connection
curl_close($curl);
//Close node server
exec('kill ' . $pid);
```

Voila! Have a look at the [demo of a node app on PHP shared hosting](http://juvenia.info/node_modules/jt-js-sample/).

**EDIT:** I started a [Node.php project on GitHub](https://github.com/niutech/node.php).

Comment: and installing mongoDB too?

Comment: @jsky It should be possible since mongodb doesn't need root. Just follow the [manual install guide](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-linux/).

Comment: @niutech What about in Windows with XAMPP?

Comment: What if Host provider know's this trick and removes our node instance an other files?

Comment: @user2118784: Windows doesn't have `wget`, `kill`, `tar`, etc. I may work with cygwin, but it's not supported.
@Nirus: It depends on hosting Terms of Service, but usually your files belong to you and they cannot delete them.

Comment: Really Good One, But how to install Phantomjs using node.php

Comment: Be advised you shall update the [download URL](http://nodejs.org/en/download/) accordingly

Comment: node.php is very good!

Comment: @niutech, the page says to switch to admin mode, how do i do this?

Comment: @smerny By setting `ADMIN_MODE` to `true` on line 13 of node.php

Comment: Error requesting node_modules/bower/: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 49999: Connection refused

Comment: @MiomirDancevic It means the `node` process didn't start. Try going through [troubleshooting](https://github.com/niutech/node.php#troubleshooting).

Comment: So I can use socket.io too? wow nice triks. haha

Comment: Cool trick, though keep in mind a lot of shared hosting providers will kill this process and consider it misuse of a shared hosting account...

Comment: `Fatal error:  Call to undefined function curl_init()` Aww. Do I have any chances?

Comment: @kim366 See https://github.com/niutech/node.php/issues/32

Comment: won't shared services have restrictions against curl?

Comment: @NevilleNazerane node.php uses PHP cURL, whch is enabled by most sharing hosts.

Comment: @knnhcn yes, I can confirm it works

Comment: `usleep(500000);` half second of wait on each request?

Comment: God this error when running  `http://example.org/node.php?npm=install jt-js-sample` : `Running: node/bin/npm --cache ./.npm -- install jt-js-sample
Failed. Error: 127. See npm-debug.log`

Answer (score 72):

Connect with SSH and follow these [instructions to install Node on a shared hosting](http://vinyll.scopyleft.fr/installing-a-custom-version-of-node-on-a-shared-hosting/)

In short you first install NVM, then you install the Node version of your choice with NVM.

```
wget -qO- https://cdn.rawgit.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | bash
```

Your restart your shell (close and reopen your sessions). Then you

```
nvm install stable
```

to install the latest stable version for example. You can install any version of your choice. Check `node --version` for the node version you are currently using and `nvm list` to see what you've installed.

In bonus you can switch version very easily (`nvm use <version>`)

There's no need of PHP or whichever tricky workaround if you have SSH.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Although, I am running into trouble, it says that node is not found, once I do the install using nvm. Any help?

Comment: Maybe should you try http://stackoverflow.com/a/33874050/328117 if you have that _node not found_ error with nvm

Comment: Most shared hosting providers don't give SSH access. At least not mine.

Comment: This worked on a shared host on hostgator

Comment: Worked perfectly!! Thanks

Comment: hi...after i follow the first step...and then i try to run "nvm install stable"...but it said "nvm: command not found" ...what is the problem?

Comment: Nodejs and Npm install complete. How to run app on domain?

Comment: @SyamsoulAzrien if you got `nvm:command not found` you can run this: command `source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh`

Comment: This config change to public_html/.htaccess worked: https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/installable-applications/manual-installations/installing-node-js-on-managed-hosting-accounts

Comment: the wget command failed to work for me on shared GoDaddy hosting, I had to download the install.sh file to my local system and manually upload to the server and then run `bash install,sh` @SyamsoulAzrien maybe try this

Comment: if the give command with `wget` doesn't work for you, try using curl >> `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.3/install.sh | bash`

Comment: LOLLL thanks millions of times !

Answer (score 13):

I installed Node.js on bluehost.com (a shared server) using:

```
wget <path to download file>
tar -xf <gzip file>
mv <gzip_file_dir> node
```

This will download the tar file, extract to a directory and then rename that directory to the name 'node' to make it easier to use.

then

```
./node/bin/npm install jt-js-sample

Returns:
npm WARN engine jt-js-sample@0.2.4: wanted: {"node":"0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.4","npm":"2.10.1"})
jt-js-sample@0.2.4 node_modules/jt-js-sample
└── express@4.12.4 (merge-descriptors@1.0.0, utils-merge@1.0.0, cookie-signature@1.0.6, methods@1.1.1, cookie@0.1.2, fresh@0.2.4, escape-html@1.0.1, range-parser@1.0.2, finalhandler@0.3.6, content-type@1.0.1, vary@1.0.0, parseurl@1.3.0, serve-static@1.9.3, content-disposition@0.5.0, path-to-regexp@0.1.3, depd@1.0.1, qs@2.4.2, on-finished@2.2.1, debug@2.2.0, etag@1.6.0, proxy-addr@1.0.8, send@0.12.3, type-is@1.6.2, accepts@1.2.7)
```

I can now use the commands:

```
# ~/node/bin/node -v
v0.12.4

# ~/node/bin/npm -v
2.10.1
```

For security reasons, I have renamed my node directory to something else.

Comment: I tried `npm start` in the `jt-js-sample` and I went to mysite.com:5000 but it said page not available. Do I need to go to the IP address instead?

Comment: that port is probably blocked, you should use the standard 80 port

Comment: ~/node/bin/npm -v  gives me an error saying:  let notifier = require('update-notifier')({pkg})    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:69:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:432:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:349:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:305:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:490:10)
    at startup (node.js:123:16)
    at node.js:1027:3

Answer (score 12):

A2 Hosting permits node.js on their shared hosting accounts.  I can vouch that I've had a positive experience with them.

Here are instructions in their KnowledgeBase for installing node.js using Apache/LiteSpeed as a reverse proxy: https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/installable-applications/manual-installations/installing-node-js-on-managed-hosting-accounts .  It takes about 30 minutes to set up the configuration, and it'll work with npm, Express, MySQL, etc.

See a2hosting.com.

Comment: Thank you! Just what I was looking for.

Comment: Almost two years later, A2 Hosting is still one of the very few hosting providers _officially_ supporting Node.js on their shared servers. A recent getting started guide can be found [here](https://www.ionicrun.com/running-a-node-js-application-on-shared-hosting/)

Comment: does react and front end run well on shared node js hosting plan ? any idea

Comment: Wrote a blog on the same. https://medium.com/@pampas93/host-your-node-js-app-on-shared-hosting-go-beyond-localhost-73ab923e6691

Answer (score 3):

You should look for a hosting company that provides such feature, but standard simple static+PHP+MySQL hosting won't let you use node.js.

You need either find a hosting designed for node.js or buy a [Virtual Private Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server) and install it yourself.

Comment: do you mean it is not possible to host Node.js application using shared hosting

Comment: @somesh It is possible - see my answer.

Comment: It's a cool trick, though keep in mind a lot of shared hosting providers will kill this process and consider it misuse of a shared hosting account...

Comment: technically possible as @niutech said, but I definitely wouldn't consider it production safe, other colleague (cannot mention more than one user) is right, I believe most hosting providers will kill the  node process or you would run out of processor cycle time very soon