# Deploy Node.js with Vue.js app to Hostinger

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js, web-hosting

I am a beginner at vue and node.
I want to deploy a Vue.js app that uses an express api on different ports. The problem is that I do not know how to deploy the app so that the api works aswell.
The api connects to a MySQL database that is hosted on Hostinger. I have already bought a Hostinger Business Web Hosting and am not sure how to continue. 
Until now, locally I used the package.json to start the "node api.js" and the "vue-cli-service serve" at the same time, but I am not sure how this could will work in production.

I have also seen some approaches with PM2, but they are not clear enough for me.

Answer (score 0):

As I know it is impossible to host node.js app on hostinger Business Web Hosting. You better connect hostinger support. They have live chat and are always glad to help.

Comment: You can host it, If you brought VPS

Comment: if he buys VPS, yes he can host it.

Answer (score 0):

I asked question like that about how to install nodejs to shared hosting. You can try to install nodejs if success you can install vuejs too. [Here Link of my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33322946/install-nodejs-on-shared-server)

Answer (score 0):

I just talked to their customer support and as the others mentioned, you have to buy VPS for that :(

You can manually upload it ([tutorial](https://medium.com/@hiddendreamz7/deploy-vue-js-site-an-easy-approach-dcfe3c2e166d)), but that is not ideal, to be honest.
You can get a little cheeky and create a second repository, where you deploy your dist folder (which is automatically created when you run `npm run build`). Then you can automatically hook that repository with Hostinger. I have tried that out and it works :)
You could think about automating the updates on the second repository with workflows, but I haven't done that so far.

As a side note:
For quick deployment, [Netlify](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#netlify) allows makes it easy for simple applications. However, in your case, this option might not suit your situation as the backend might pose a problem to deploy.