# NPM not found when using NVM

Tags: node.js, npm, nvm

I have installed node/npm using the nvm documentation.

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.29.0/install.sh | bash
```

Then:

```
nvm install node
```

At this point node is working but the npm command result with:

```
npm: command not found
```

How can I have npm to work correctly ?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I found out that this was a conflict with a previous versions of npm that have not been removed properly despite a `apt-get remove node`.

I solved it by reinstalling npm from scratch:

```
rm -R ~/.npm ~/.nvm
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash
nvm install node
```

I found the solution [here](https://andyj.github.io/posts/npm-not-found-with-nvm.html).

Comment: Just a note to anyone copying and pasting the whole string: you'll probably want to use [a newer version of the nvm install script](https://github.com/creationix/nvm#installation).

Comment: Updated the link. However, like said, latest can be always found from the repository.

Comment: Didn't work for me--I never had nodejs, npm, or nvm installed, tried with this anyway: `apt-get update --quiet && apt-get purge -y nodejs npm && apt-get autoremove -y && rm -rf ~/.npm ~/.nvm && apt-get clean`

Answer (score 49):

If you run NVM-Windows, don't forget to run `nvm on`. (this solve the problem as title for me.)

Comment: doesnt work. maybe because i did not install previous node using installer? i manually configure environment path

Comment: worked for me! This is why windows is frustrating

Comment: this is the answer for me

Comment: This worked for me, thanks!

Comment: It changed the version to the latest. I needed to use 10, now it's 20. So not the answer for me.

Answer (score 19):

I fixed this by doing this command:

`$ command -v npm`

and then reopen the shell window.

Comment: For me, this worked and not the accepted answer as I had no installations of npm previously.

Comment: I think this allow npm to get in your shell again after installing nvm... for more details read this question -> https://askubuntu.com/questions/512770/what-is-use-of-command-command

Answer (score 8):

I solved it by uninstalling all problematic node versions (e.g. v14 below) and reinstalling it.

The problem:

```sh
node --version; npm --version;
```

```
v14.17.1
Command 'npm' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install npm
```

The solution:

```sh
nvm deactivate

echo "All versions BEFORE:"
nvm_ls

# uninstall all 14.* versions
for v in $(nvm_ls 14); do nvm uninstall $v; done

echo "All versions AFTER:"
nvm_ls

# reinstall version 14
nvm install 14

# and now it has npm too
node --version; npm --version
which node; which npm

# v14.17.1
# 6.14.13
# /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.1/bin/node
# /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.1/bin/npm
```

Comment: as npm need updated by nvm, just use `nvm install 16`, and there you go (for laravel 10)

Answer (score 7):

If you use Windows OS, make sure you removed the existing nodejs and npm.
In my case, it worked well after I remove the C:/Program Files/nodejs.
Reference is [here](http://techbrij.com/nvm-windows-node-npm-not-recognized).

> During nvm installation, make sure the selected path must NOT exist.

Answer (score 6):

This problem especially happens in windows which happens because of missing admin rights for cmd.

If you are using Git bash

1. Go in installation directory e.g C:\Program Files\Git
2. Right click properties -> compatibility.
3. Tick the checkbox with label -> Run as administrator.
4. Run the git bash again & execute npm list and then npm use 'version_to_be_used'

Same goes for Cmd

Answer (score 4):

One possible reason is the NVM symlink is invalid.

1. But first, check if both `NVM_HOME` & `NVM_SYMLINK` is already set in environment path.
   If not, maybe some problem with your nvm installation and u might want to reinstall.
2. Using explorer, open the symlink folder to check if the folder is valid.
   **Default Symlink path in Windows: `C:\Program Files\nodejs`. Symlink appears as a normal shortcut in Windows explorer.**
   If you see node files in there, then you're fine.
   If the folder is invalid, delete the symlink. 
   Then, execute `nvm ls` and `nvm use <desired node version>`, this step will re-create the correct symlink.
3. Restart CMD and test `nvm current`, `node -v`, `npm -v`

Comment: your point 2 saves me. thank you!

Answer (score 3):

For me, it only worked in Windows after

1. reinstalling nvm through the [.exe package](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases/download/1.1.11/nvm-setup.exe), and
2. reinstalling node version in a way that Windows is able to add everything properly to environment variables

- **nvm uninstall < *nodeversion* >**
- **nvm install < *nodeversion* >**
- **nvm use < *node version* >**
- **npm -v** *should display your npm version*

Remember to run everything in a prompt as administrator to avoid symlink permission issues.

Comment: Administrator mode... that was it for me.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows:

nvm creating symlink from installed node path like c:\program files\node  to the c:\users<your user>\AppData\nvm<node ver>

So check:

1. Your basic node path in the PATH variable.
2. Your npm is inside c:\users<your user>\AppData\nvm<node ver>\nmp   and this path is also int the PATH variable.

Answer (score 1):

You could also run

**source ~/.bashrc**

and try to run again on the same bash terminal where you downloaded the install.sh the command:

**npm -v**

Answer (score 1):

I went through a similar issue recently and solved it by setting the npm mirror to npm_mirror https://github.com/npm/cli/archive/refs/tags/

The default npm mirror (https://github.com/npm/cli/archive) was a broken link.

so run

```
nvm npm_mirror https://github.com/npm/cli/archive/refs/tags/
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was that when installing NVM I did not define the default version, check if this is your case by running the command:

nvm list

If the data: "**default**" is similar to "**default -> lts (-> N/A)**"

You have the same problem as I had, let's solve it by doing the following:

After installing nvm, run the command: "**nvm install node --lts**" without the quotes!

If everything goes well, it will display something like:

*Installing latest LTS version.*
*Now using node v18.18.0 (npm v10.1.0)*

In my case, note that the exact installed version of lts was "**v18.18.0**" you need to set a default version otherwise, running the nvm list command you will see that the nvm default will be set to N/A

If after running the "**nvm list**" command you notice that the "**default**" parameter is:

**default -> lts (-> N/A)**

It means that the default version for use has not been defined, which is why you can run nvm in the terminal, but you cannot run npm or node -v

So finally, resolve this by setting the default version for NVM:

Run: "**nvm list**" and see if it appears in the list: "**lts/hydrogen -> v18.18.0**"

Now run: "**nvm alias default lts/hydrogen**"
If ok, it will display the message: "*default -> lts/hydrogen (-> v18.18.0)*"

Finish with the command: "**nvm use default**"
If ok, it will display the message:
"*Now using node v18.18.0 (npm v10.1.0)*"

Checking before and after running the "**nvm list**" command

Before:
*default -> lts (-> N/A)*

After:
*default -> lts/hydrogen (-> v18.18.0)*

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while any new terminal instance started up the message 'npm not found' was shown. I noticed that I had defined (probably) custom paths to `npm` and `node` in **`~/.bashrc`**. Deleting them (keeping the paths for nvm) resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This helped me: https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/issues/548#issuecomment-768297716 Adding quotes to NVM_SYMLINK environment variable: `"C:\Program Files\nodejs"` instead of `C:\Program Files\nodejs`.

Answer (score 0):

**A.** Also see troubleshooting section at nvm documentation:

https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#troubleshooting-on-linux

> Troubleshooting on Linux On Linux, after running the install script,
> if you get nvm: command not found or see no feedback from your
> terminal after you type command -v nvm, simply close your current
> terminal, open a new terminal, and try verifying again. Alternatively,
> you can run the following commands for the different shells on the
> command line:
>
> bash: source ~/.bashrc
>
> zsh: source ~/.zshrc
>
> ksh: . ~/.profile
>
> These should pick up the nvm command.

**B.** If you want to use the npm command in a **Docker** file, consider to append it to the nvm command, for example

```
ENV NVM_DIR /root/.nvm
ENV NODE_VERSION 18.17.0 # 20.10.0 is not supported by geneator-office, yet

RUN curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.39.7/install.sh | bash \
  && . $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh \ 
  && nvm install $NODE_VERSION \ 
  && nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION \
  && nvm use default \
  && npm install -g npm \
  && npm install -g yo generator-office
```

instead of

```
RUN curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.39.7/install.sh | bash \
  && . $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh \ 
  && nvm install $NODE_VERSION \ 
  && nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION \
  && nvm use default \

RUN npm install -g npm 
RUN npm install -g yo generator-office
```

Answer (score 0):

For all those who are **still trying to install** NVM on Windows and all the tips here have not helped: try the following (this was the only thing that worked for me).

I think the main problem is that probably most people here were already using Nodejs before installing NVM - therefore there's most likely an old NodeJS folder under `C:\Program Files\nodejs`.

Now try to uninstall NVM and Nodejs, and do not forget to remove the folder `C:\Program Files\nodejs` manually (!!!).
Then reinstall NVM **with administrator rights** (I used the compiled installer from NVM - repository).

Now do these steps:

1. Open a new command line CMD.exe
2. Try to verify, if nvm is installed by typing: `nvm --version`
3. And then go ahead with: `nvm install latest`
4. `nvm use [here comes your version]`
5. `nvm on`

This finally (!!!) worked for me!

Answer (score -3):

Install node using node source distribution:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_[version].x | bash -
apt-get install -y nodejs
```

[version] = the wanted version. See the repository to choose the correct: [NodeSource Node.js Binary Distributions](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions)

Comment: nvm also installs node using the source distribution. However, nvm retains node versions so you can quickly upgrade and re-install all global modules.

Comment: That's not what the question asks. It would be kind to not to suggest to just use something else as an answer since it doesn't answer to OP's question, unless necessary. OP Clearly uses NVM for a reason (eg. can switch between node versions).