# npm list is not pointing to the node_modules folder

Tags: node.js, terminal, npm, nvm

I have recently install nvm, node and npm. I cant seem to get the $npm list to list the modules in the node_modules folder. Other npm commands work. npm install -g installs in the correct folder which I can see by cd'ing to it. I cant figure out why one npm command works but the next doesnt. npm config shows cwd as a different folder. Do I have to change that? If so, how do i do that? Thank you.

https://gist.github.com/kaona/0d5ba467cff814dbb1691a083baa1dee

I also tried [this](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/3674) but didnt work. I know its something simple im missing. Still new to this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you included the modules in your `package.json` file? The `npm list` command won't show a module if its not in the package.json, even if its installed in the `node_modules` directory.

> The tree shown is the logical dependency tree, based on package dependencies, not the physical layout of your node_modules folder.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls

When you install a module into your app, use the `--save` or `--save-dev` options to update your `package.json`. This allows you to install all the dependencies of your application by running `npm install`. It will also mean that your modules show up when you use the `npm list` command.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install - For more details

Comment: ok, so i must use npm ls -g for globally installed modules. That's good to note. Thank you. As i just installed nvm, i went ahead and removed nvm and npm per advice [here](https://andyj.github.io/posts/npm-not-found-with-nvm.html) & [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33874049/npm-not-found-when-using-nvm). Now, in project,  i'm getting -bash: webpack: command not found. Which tells me npm is not in my path. I tried `My-MacBook-Pro:~ klik$ echo $(npm config get prefix)/bin.
/usr/local/bin.
My-MacBook-Pro:~ klik$ export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin.' restarted. no joy. Is this diff in NVM?

Comment: thanks for the help. That got me to the next problem which i worked out. Much appreciated.