# Running Node App on Shared Hosting (It's almost working)

Tags: node.js, shared-hosting

I've managed to get Node and NPM installed on my shared hosting account with Namecheap [by following this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33857377/6740765). It all seems to be working, I can launch my app and it stays launched, but the subdomain which points to app's root route just shows up the folder of the domain.

I've tried going to myaddress.com/subdomain:8080 but I get a server error plus a 404. I've also tried changing Node's listening port from 8080 to 80, but on 80 I get an error:

```
Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:80
```

So that means I don't have rights to port 80. How can I get clients to connect port 8080?

Answer (score 1):

This is the part that shared hosting has a problem with, they wont open any ports for you.  This is exactly where your workaround needs to be centered.  Im currently looking for solutions to either use php to serve a node 
see here https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-php-server 
and here [How to host a Node.Js application in shared hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777750/how-to-host-a-node-js-application-in-shared-hosting/33857377#33857377) 
or just configuring `express` to use somehow port 80.

These would be your best options.