# "Process out of memory" error after installing node from source

Tags: node.js, installation, shared-hosting

I'm trying to install NodeJS on shared hosting. I downloaded the source from

https://nodejs.org/en/download/

and followed the usual install procedure with `./config --prefix="$HOME/local"`.

It compiles without error. However, when I try to run it, I get the following error:

```
installing /kunden/homepages/32/d690510543/htdocs/local/include/node/zconf.h
installing /kunden/homepages/32/d690510543/htdocs/local/include/node/zlib.h
(uiserver):xxxxxxxx:~/node-v8.11.2$ which node
/kunden/homepages/32/d690510543/htdocs/local/bin/node
(uiserver):xxxxxxxx:~/node-v8.11.2$ node


#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# API fatal error handler returned after process out of memory
#
Illegal instruction
```

However, I can get the version

```
$ node -v
v8.11.2
```

and help.

Nevertheless, I can't run a script

```
(uiserver):xxxxxxxx:~$ cat hello.js
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.end('Hello World\n');
        }).listen(1337, "127.0.0.1");
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
(uiserver):xxxxxxxx:~$ node hello.js


#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# API fatal error handler returned after process out of memory
#
Illegal instruction
```

Nor can I enter the REPL:

(uiserver):xxxxxxxx:~$ node -i

#

## Fatal error in , line 0

## API fatal error handler returned after process out of memory

#
Illegal instruction

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and what i realized was that it was only occuring when i use mlab sandbox mongo db.Initially everything was ok  even with mlab mongo db but all over sudden i the error started appearing .I changed to locally installed mongodb and all was well,i deleted my mlab mongo db collections and changed back to mlab,all was well again.I guess the issue is with mlab free tier limitations

Answer (score 0):

When I execute  my Vue.js project with command:

```
npm  run dev
```

in webstorm console, the console output:

```
# Fatal error in , line 0
# API fatal error handler returned after process out of memory
```

Then when I restart use command:

```
npm run dev
```

webstorm crashes, I restart webstorm and use command:

```
npm run dev
```

a second time, and it works. So I think it is because that my computer memory is not enough when webstorm starts too many child processes.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue (and afaik the same hosting provider). However, **installing node through nvm**, like described e.g. at https://stackoverflow.com/a/33857377/1680728 did solve the issue for me. I do not know whether its some environment setting or has to do with the fetched binaries/version.

So, I cannot solve the "Process out of memory" error, but I guess the real problem was to have any nodejs version running on a shared host.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I close my webstorme and try again