# NodeJS Express Website Error 403 on public server

Tags: node.js, express, http-status-code-403

I have a super simple NodeJS Express site setup with the following Folder Structure:

[image]

Views just contains a singe file `index.ejs` and public just a few `.css` and `.js` files required to make my site work (bootstrap, jquery etc.).

Using this on my local machine works great, however, the moment I put it on my live server (Shared Hosting on A2 Hosting), trying to open the page gives me Error 403, any ideas of what I'm missing?

Here is my `servers.js` file:

```
var express = require('express'),
path = require('path'),
nodeMailer = require('nodemailer'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());   
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index');
});
```

Comment: on what port your app is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried all steps in their tutorial?
https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/installable-applications/manual-installations/installing-node-js-on-managed-hosting-accounts

Found it on StackOverflow:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32535632

PS: I would prefer to write this as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation yet.