# uploading my Socket.io and node.js application to a server

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

So i just finished up my Socket.io application (instant Messenger) and I usually build and use these applications in localhost. But for this I want to upload it to a server so others may use it! I'm just kind of confused on how i would get some stuff working, like connecting to my JS file using node.js on a server and such. I have a small shared server with GoDaddy i was planning to upload this to, so my question is it possible to upload my files to a shared server and have node.js running on my PC? Or am I looking like a complete fool and asking something that can not be easily done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need nodejs on your server so you can run your web service. You may want to consider signing up for [AWS](http://aws.amazon.com/) or any other cloud hosting service and launch your own virtual server running a nodejs stack, its free for one year.

Then you just need to upload your files to the server and run them using nodejs.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean, could you explain a little bit more?

Comment: You need access to a server that has nodejs installed, then you upload your file to it and execute nodejs on the server with the path of the file as argument. Just like you probably did on your own machine to develop your application.

Comment: Maybe this post makes things clearer for you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529613/why-node-js-cant-run-on-shared-hosting