# How to install nodejs application in Godaddy server

Tags: node.js

I begun with `nodejs` and `express framework.`

In localhost its ok i can run my app, but i would like to know how can i use it in my website that host in godaddy server.

I use to execute just php but nodejs i don't know how can i do that.

In local, I write in command line:

```
node app.js
```

or

```
npm start
```

with package.json, but in Godaddy I can't use commandline to start the app.

Comment: It seems that you are using shared hosting. Please see this answer for an explanation as to why this can't be done http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529613/why-node-js-cant-run-on-shared-hosting

Comment: This question would be better suited for webmasters or serverfault, depending on whether it is in a professional context or not.

Comment: I got node working with godaddy shared hosting cpanel by using ssh. I downloaded the binaries from ssh and extracted it and I was able to test the version and use npm start.

Comment: Should we re-open this? Accepted answer and overall answers are trapped in the past and not true anymore.

Comment: You can add a new answer. Thanks @Frederik.L

Answer (score 20):

Our shared hosting does not have node support. Right now your best bet is to get a virtual dedicated server but in the near future we'll have some additional options that will be priced closer to the Shared price point but with Node support. Hope this helps!

Comment: any update on this? @colby-GoDaddy

Comment: Heard the news that nodejitsu joined you, so now any update on this?

Comment: Sorry all, no update as of yet. ^Colby

Comment: is that tutorial possible? http://www.cgi-node.org/docs/cgi-node-on-godaddy-tutorial

Comment: @Colby-GoDaddy - Any update on this?

Comment: @Colby-GoDaddy Hi Colby. I heard that Nodejitsu is merging with GoDaddy. Any update?

Comment: Too bad this question is closed. ANSWER - GoDaddy now has great support for hosting NodeJS - look for the 'Cloud Server'. Here is a link to details: https://www.godaddy.com/pro/cloud-servers and https://www.godaddy.com/pro/one-click-installation/node-js . The reason I love it is the cheapest hosting option.

Comment: How much does it cost, cant see the price...

Answer (score 14):

GoDaddy doesn't support Node as far as I know, the server has to have Node installed for your command to run.  Consider Heroku or NodeJitsu if you want Node hosting.  Plus, they're free at a first tier and a much better product in my experience than GoDaddy.

Comment: Godaddy bought NodeJitsu in Feb 15.

Comment: try amazon mate it has a great support of nodejs.

Comment: yeah no longer accurate.

Comment: Too bad this question is closed. ANSWER - GoDaddy now has great support for hosting NodeJS - look for the 'Cloud Server'. Here is a link to details: https://www.godaddy.com/pro/cloud-servers and https://www.godaddy.com/pro/one-click-installation/node-js . The reason I love it is the cheapest hosting option.

Comment: How can you say it's the cheapest option when there are free tier plans available elsewhere that are not capped at 30days?