# How to use node.js on host server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-hosting

I need your help regarding node.js. I just finished a course and I want to run my code on a web hosting.

The problem is, that when I upload it per ftp, I won't see it as website (even though it has html tags in it) but as code. Is it because the web hosting isn't compatible with node.js? Or is there anything I should do beside requiring express?

Is there anything I should install or do?

The code works totally fine if I go through localhost.

Thank you a lot in advance!
TheGabornator

Comment: If it's a shared hosting, you need to ask the hoster if he can install the NodeJS modules for you. Or you can search for a host with nodejs functions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why node.js can't run on shared hosting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529613/why-node-js-cant-run-on-shared-hosting)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it because the web hosting isn't compatible with node.js?

Yes.

> Is there anything I should install or do?

If your only access to the host is via FTP or some web based UI, then you almost certainly need to change host. You're unlikely to have a host which lets you run Node.JS applications unless they offer you full shell access.

You need either a host which explicitly supports Node.JS or one which gives you full shell access and allows you to install software (such as a virtual machine or dedicated server).

Comment: Thank you so much! No, I can go through the website of the provider too if that's what you mean. Great, I will ask them then.