# why can't i use node.js on shared server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, shared-hosting

I'm sure to the experts I will sound like a noob... very new to node.js. One of the thing I've just learnt is that I can start a basic server with something like this..

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello World");
  response.end();
}).listen(8888);
```

now  i can access on cli with

```
$ node the-above-code.js
```

why can't the same be achieved on a shared server e.g. godaddy? What are the conceptual problems in that?

Comment: The first limit when you use a shared virtual host like Godaddy may be that it doesn't allow you to bind your app to listen to port like `8888`. Second of all a typical shared virtual host would not let you have access to install/change any system level dependencies so Node.js may not even exist or not exposed for you to access in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that godaddy doesn't let you change the apache settings to let you bind to port 8888.  You would have to get yourself a private server to do that.

Refer to this thread:
[Why node.js can't run on shared hosting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529613/why-node-js-cant-run-on-shared-hosting)