# How to restart NodeJS with cPanel

Tags: node.js, cpanel, application-restart

I need to know what to use from root side of cPanel based server to restart NodeJS app, for example, if process terminated now for some reasons NodeJS app will not start until I manually start it, same if server restart I need manually to restart it.

Also, this is case for several accounts on server, command should allow more apps to be restarted/started.

Any help would be great

Answer (score 2):

Here is an automated way to do the it:
- Find if node server [eq. server.js] is running or not.
- If server is not running, restart by "nodemon server.js".
- Else if server is running, do nothing.

You can code this in bash script [sample code below] and set up a CRON job in your cpanel to run it after a particular time.

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="server.js" # nodejs script's name here
RUN=`pgrep -f $NAME`

if [ "$RUN" == "" ]; then
  nodemon server.js
else
  echo "Script is running"
fi
```

Comment: I use like this, but it show error: https://s33.postimg.cc/vfa7cpmnz/20180515_213815.jpg

and if I execute over SSH: pm2 start mooServer.js it work fine, but over cron it is missing pid as you can see in screenshot.

#!/bin/bash

NAME="mooServer.js" # nodejs script's name here
RUN=`pgrep -f $NAME`

if [ "$RUN" == "" ]; then
  /home/preppers/bin/node /home/preppers/bin/pm2 start /home/preppers/public_html/lib/MooNodeJsServer/mooServer.js
else
  echo "Script is running"
fi

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend running your `node` app using `PM2`.

`npm install pm2 -g`
`pm2 start app.js`
`pm2 restart app`

If you are using `node` or `nodemon` on Linux machine I'd recommend using `PM2` to manage the service. It is a lot more stable that `nodemon` and offers other production level features like `console.log` to `console.error` file and

https://pm2.io/doc/en/runtime/features/commands-cheatsheet/

Answer (score 0):

I just used a crone job to run the following command once every 5mins

```
~/bin/node ~/backends/api/app.js
```

I was having problems with nodemon, it was saying it's not a command blah blah so I thought of just directing straight to node and directly to my app.

This is working for my use case coz the app bails if the addr is being used. So if it crashed then it will restart it since it won't occupy the addr.