# can i host nodejs react project on hostinger shared hosting?

Tags: node.js, hosting

I have read many articles posting about shared hosting on multiple hosting platforms.
but i still want to be sure that can I host react and nodejs project on hostinger on their shared hosting plan.

Or can someone suggest me a better hosting I am using MySQL as a database.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can host nodejs app on Hostinger, but since hpanel (hostinger's replacement for cpanel) does not have one-click node.js install, you need to install noedjs manually and it is may be a complex process.
Hostinger's shared hosting is specially optimised for wordpress (and other PHP CMS).

If you are just trying out apps, better go for Heroku for now.
If professional, you can go with any hosting providers with cpanel for easy nodejs installation.

In case you want to install nodejs on hostinger, pls refer to below answer -
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63769404/5028003

Answer (score 2):

Hostinger does not allow node.js on their shared plans. To have a node.js app you will need to user their VPS service.