# How to install node.js source code through cpanel filemanager

Tags: node.js

***Hey guys... I have a complete web project source code built with node.js, but am trying to install it on shared hosting using cpanel file manager, and have uploaded and connected the database and SQL database but when I run the app on browser keep showing index page and all file uploaded...***

***I need help guys...***

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run node.js on cpanel hosting server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44079039/run-node-js-on-cpanel-hosting-server)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44079039/run-node-js-on-cpanel-hosting-server